# Can shapeless Record type be used as a Poly1?

Tags: scala, shapeless, polymorphic-functions

Assuming if I have the following Record typed data, and a hlist of keys:

```
    val rr = ("a" ->> 1) ::
      ("b" -> "s") ::
      ("c" -> 3) ::
      HNil

val hh = "c" :: "b" :: HNil
```

And I want to extract values in `rr` for each key in `hh`, then combine them into a type level object, eventually yielding:

```
(3: Int) :: ("s": String) :: HNil
```

How this can be achieved with least amount of code? I could obviously write a inductively-summoned implicit function but it seems to be overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have typos. `->>` should be instead of `->`.

Secondly, `val hh = "c" :: "b" :: HNil` doesn't have type `"c" :: "b" :: HNil`, it has type `String :: String :: HNil` instead (so you're loosing compile-time information about keys). If you want `hh` to have type `"c" :: "b" :: HNil` (so that values with such keys can be extracted from `rr`) then you should use `.narrow`

```
type hht = "c" :: "b" :: HNil
val hh: hht = "c".narrow :: "b".narrow :: HNil
```

Thirdly, if you want to extract a value from a record by a key you should use type class `shapeless.ops.record.Selector`. If you want to extract several values by several keys you should use type class `shapeless.ops.record.SelectAll`. There is extension method `get`/`apply` defined via `Selector` in `shapeless.record._` but I can't find the one defined via `SelectAll` so you can define it yourself similarly to `get`/`apply`

```
implicit class RecordOps[L <: HList](val l : L) {
  def getAll[K <: HList](k: K)(implicit selector: SelectAll[L, K]): selector.Out = 
    selector(l)
  def getAllByType[K <: HList](implicit selector: SelectAll[L, K]): selector.Out = 
    selector(l)
}

rr.getAll(hh) // 3 :: s :: HNil
rr.getAllByType[hht] // 3 :: s :: HNil
```