# In scala shapeless, how to use Record.updateWith inside another method?

Tags: scala, typeclass, shapeless, scala-2.13, recordtype

From what I have read online, the shapeless Record.updateWith seems to be the only way to update both the value & type of a Record entry. So I gave it a try:

```
  import shapeless.syntax.singleton.mkSingletonOps
  import shapeless.record._

    val existing = ("i" ->> 3.0) :: ("j" ->> "Abc") :: HNil

    val uu = existing.updateWith("i")(_ => 123)
```

It worked! the output is `123 :: Abc :: HNil`, however I encounter a different problem: I cannot call this function inside another function, namely, it cannot use typeclasses in scope:

```
    def update[HH <: HList, O](existing: HH, k: Witness.Lt[String], v: Int)(
        implicit
        lemma1: Selector.Aux[HH, k.T, O],
        lemma2: Modifier[HH, k.T, O, Int]
    ) = {

      val result = existing.updateWith(k.value)(_ => v)
      result
    }
```

The latest compiler (2.13.4) gave the following error information:

```
[Error] ... : Unable to resolve implicit value of type shapeless.ops.record.Selector[HH,Witness.this.value.type]
one error found
```

Despite that `lemma1` totally qualifies this condition. So my questions are:

- How do I instruct the type class summoner of `updateWith` to use `lemma1`? (it is written in macro)
- If this is not possible, what are my other options to implement a proper update in a method?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Despite that lemma1 totally qualifies this condition.

No, it doesn't. `Selector[HH, k.T]` and `Selector[HH, k.value.type]` are different types. `k.value.type` is a subtype of `k.T`. `Selector` is invariant.

I already [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66036106/can-shapeless-record-type-be-used-as-a-poly1-part-2/) you to use type classes rather than extension methods

```
def update[HH <: HList, O](existing: HH, k: Witness.Lt[String], v: Int)(
  implicit
  lemma1: Selector.Aux[HH, k.T, O],
  lemma2: Modifier[HH, k.T, O, Int]
) = {
  lemma2(existing, _ => v)
}
```

or

```
def update[HH <: HList, K <: String, O](existing: HH, k: K, v: Int)(
  implicit
  witness: Witness.Aux[K],
  lemma1: Selector.Aux[HH, K, O],
  lemma2: Modifier[HH, K, O, Int]
) = {
  lemma2(existing, _ => v)
}
```

Comment: ahhh ... yes, will identify the pattern in the future: don't summon the type class if it can be used directly